# How to stay logged in permanently using apache shiro

Tags: java, jsf, authentication, shiro

A need to know how to stay logged in permanently in my Java EE application when the user logged in at first time using apache shiro

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shiro supports "Remember me" facility. Just provide a checkbox with name `rememberMe` in the login form:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" value="true" />
```

If you want to use JSF `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` as follows,

```html
<h:form id="login">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="rememberMe" />
```

Then you need to alter the `shiro.ini` to add the following entry under `[main]`:

```
authc.rememberMeParam = login:rememberMe
```

where `login:rememberMe` is the JSF-generated client ID of the checkbox, representing the actual HTTP request parameter name.

If you want to have it checked by default, use `checked="checked"` in the HTML input, or provide a `boolean=true` property in the JSF component.

#### See also:

- [JSF2 - Shiro tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html)