# When a session expires in Apache Shiro, how can users stay logged in?

Tags: java, tomcat, cookies, shiro

What it happens in my project is after expiring session or reset Apache Tomcat, all of my user logged out automatically and need to login again. How to fix problem to users stay logged in?

This is my Apache Shiro INI Configuration:

```
[main]
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager

securityManager.sessionMode = native

sessionDAO = org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO
securityManager.sessionManager.sessionDAO = $sessionDAO

cookie = org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie
cookie.name = bzauth
cookie.path = /
securityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdCookie = $cookie

cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager
```

Comment: try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917360/how-to-stay-logged-in-permanently-using-apache-shiro

Comment: I just want to know the use case here. Its good to logout the user if session expires.

Comment: @RajindRuparathna i'm use rememberMe, but logout after expire session.

Comment: @Azim is not good logout!